# Sendy.co generating errors and filling up hard drive

Tags: sendy

I am using sendy.co and although I purchased the script directly from sendy.co website I am noticing a ton of errors in my error log each time I send an email blast that says

```
Undefined array key "license" in /includes/functions.php eval()'d code on 270
```

Also

```
Undefined array key "userID" in /includes/functions.php eval()'d code on 150
```

Unfortunately, functions.php is an encrypted file and I don't want to try to reverse-engineer it. Wondering if anyone ever had this issue and how it might of been resolved.
I sent an email to the hello@sendy.co but as i wait for an answer was hoping maybe someone else came across this issue and resolved it

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem with fresh Sendy 6.0.4 after upgrading php on our server from version 7.4 to 8.2. This functions.php file uses Sessions to get 'license' and other needed data. In our case the issue was related to Session read/write access.
Try to check your **session.save_path** php value and make sure that path is available for saving and reading Session data. You should check this value in your **php.ini** file and **.htaccess** in the root folder of your site.
In our case (Nginx server) our admin wrote: "There was a left over cpanel file user.ini in the root public_html directory that was being read by the php-fpm process. It seems that php8+ reads user.ini files by default where as php7.x didn't."
That user.ini had session.save_path = '/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56'. It was wrong old path value automatically generated by cPanel. Therefore new php could not read and write session data and caused these errors:

> PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to read session data: files
> (path: /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56) in
> /.../includes/functions.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 9
>
> PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "userID" in
> /.../includes/functions.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 150
>
> PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "license" in
> /.../includes/functions.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 270
>
> ...

So **user.ini** is one more file you can check as well.

Hope it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

We experienced similar issues when using Sendy V4 after our host updated PHP to V8 which resulted in HTTP 500 errors at the login form.

Server logs showed the following errors

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: Undefined array key "userID" in 4/includes/functions.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 141

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 in includes/functions.php(1) : eval()'d code:142

mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:
mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /includes/functions.php(1) : eval()'d code(142): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'SELECT * FROM l...')

mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 /includes/header.php(2): start_app()

Our solution was to upgrade to Sendy V6

Hope this helps
Ant